# Apache CXF RS request and response sizes

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

How can i get request and response sizes in bytes in Apache CXF Rest service in order to log it in metrics db?
"content-length" is not an option, can't find such a header on my messages.
I need raw size, close enough to which i can get by WireShark, for example, when i make a tcp dump of my http session.

Comment: It seems that question is not related to CXF, but to underling servlet and servlet container. Found some answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836760/is-there-a-way-to-get-raw-http-request-stream-from-java-servlet-handler

Answer (score 0):

Refer 4.4 Message Length in the link : http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html

Content-Length Vs Transfer-Encoding and HTTP/1.0 Vs HTTP/1.1

To understand the HTTP headers & transport.

1. w.r.t. Request message, Content-Length is set by client side transport. So, it's upto the requester decision to set Content-Length or not.
2. w.r.t response message, normally based on the server on which cxf-rs endpoint is deployed. Tomcat sends the Content-Length by default. Even you can manually set the Content-Length for the response header as below:

   public Response getData() {

   Address data = new Address("London", "UK"); //domain model
                                              //Address has two properties City and Country  of type string
   return Response.ok().entity(data).type("application/json").header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, data.toString()).build();

   }